# Can not disable zipalign

Tags: android, zipalign

I have used these config in android studio 3.0.1

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

compileSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion 26.0.3


    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            testCoverageEnabled false

            multiDexEnabled true
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')

            zipAlignEnabled false
        }
    }
```

After I use Build > Generate Signed APK with release mode and then verify apk by zipalign

```
zipalign -c -v 4 release.apk
```

the result is Verification succesful
Why zipAlignEnabled false didn't work?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: I an facing the same problem. Let us know if you could resolve it.